# How to create sub-directories without HTTP or HTTPS from string parameter

Tags: linux, rhel, ksh, string

I have ksh script, which is running the below command:

```
mkdir -p down/$JENKINS_URL
```

the thing is that some $JENKINS_URL (string) includes HTTP:// and in some HTTPS://, which is causing the creation of two subdirectories under down folder, and then subdirectories for each of them.
how can I avoid it and create directly the folders name without HTTP or HTTPS under down folder?

Comment: `mkdir -p "down/${JENKINS_URL#*://}"` -- don't omit the quotes and be sure you're in control of that variable: it may break your system via `../../../../some/path`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameter substitution can be used to strip string prefixes from the `JENKINS_URL`. From the [ksh man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ksh):

> ${name#pattern}, ${name##pattern}
>
> If pattern matches the beginning of the value of parameter name, the matched text is deleted from the result of substitution. A single # results in the shortest match, two #'s results in the longest match.

As an example:

```
JENKINS_URL="http://abc"
mkdir -p "down/${JENKINS_URL#*://}"
JENKINS_URL="https://def"
echo mkdir -p "down/${JENKINS_URL#*://}"
```

The above script will strip any protocol prefix. The result of running the script is:

```
mkdir -p down/abc
mkdir -p down/def
```

Comment: Why `##`? It seems to me shortest match `#` would be more correct...

Comment: @filbranden No idea. my brain said `#` but my fingers somehow typed something else. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Tnx! it worked like magic